# $\sum a_nb_n$ convergence theorem (Rudin)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, summation-by-parts

[image]
[image]

Why does the first inequality (in the chain) hold? Is 
$$\left\lvert \sum_{n=p}^{q-1}A_n(b_n - b_{n+1})\right\lvert \le M \left\lvert \sum_{n=p}^{q-1}(b_n - b_{n+1})\right\lvert$$
true? and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed an absolute value. However, consider
$$
S:=\left|\sum_{p\le n< q}A_nc_n+A_qb_q+A_{p-1}(-b_{p-1})\right|,
$$
where $c_n:=b_n-b_{n+1}$. Since $(b_n)$ is nonincreasing then $c_n\ge 0$ for all $n$. Moreover, since $-M \le A_n \le M$ for all $n$ you have that for each real $x$ it holds
$$
\forall n,\,\,\,\,\,-M|x| \le A_n x \le M|x|.
$$
Considering the above inequality for each term $A_nc_n$, $A_qb_q$ and $A_{p-1}(-b_{p-1})$, you conclude that
$$
S\le M\left(\sum_{p\le n< q}c_n+b_q+b_{p-1}\right).
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer :). Still, I don't get the last jump! Is each term in the LHS less than each term in the RHS (multiplied by $M$)? or should I take apart the summation? Also, why is $-M\le A_n$ and $A_nx \le M|x|$? (take $A_n = -3, M=2, x=-1$). I'm sorry, but I'm really confused... May you clarify more?

Comment: Yep, your example does not work because you need $|A_n| \le M$ for each $n$. Hence, if $A_n=-3$ then $M$ is at least $3$. Moreover $|A_n| \le M$ is *equivalent* to $-M \le A_n \le M$.. Finally, if you multiply each side by $x$ (and taking care of the signs) you conclude that $-M|x| \le A_n x \le M|x|$ for all reals $x$

Comment: I got it; Thanks so much :)

Comment: You're welcome. By incidence, you get the well-known Leibniz criterion as a corollary: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test

Comment: Please! Another question that has just come to my mind. why must $c_n$ be nonnegative in order for the inequality to hold?

Comment: Because if $c_n$ would be negative then, by the above inequality, you'd need to use $|c_n|$ instead of $c_n$ (which is the same that has been done with $-b_{p-1}$)

Comment: But the absolute value already exists. For instance, if $c_n=-2$ still $|A_nc_n+...| \le M|c_n+...|$ (i.e. $c_n$ may be negative), right?

Comment: Nope the absolute value outside is unuseful (I removed it now) but in your example *inside* the big brackets you'd need the absolute value of each c_n

Comment: Mille Grazie :)